# Ubuntu and Facilities for all kind of user

Tags: customization, accessibility

In charge of the disabled website http://www.wheelchair.ch - http://www.handiplus.ch, which is aimed to deliver information and promote integration for any kind of mobility impairment, and regular ubuntu user, I would like to see more "accessibility" in it...

Why not introduce extra features for people with disability and let them have an accessible common OS ?
In that purpose, I suggest to include in a future Ubuntu versions :
 - a vocal command to help the blinded
 - a one touch command or closer commands option for quadriplegics and other people suffering of lack of mobility so that then can use Ubuntu easier without the complicated use of mouses for side to side on the screen
 - visual alerts rather sound alerts to satisfy deaf people
.... and much more facilities

I thing Ubuntu should be equally suitable to disabled than to "enabled" people. And for that matter, I am ready to bring any help I can, if necessary.

Best Regards
A.C.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: This was an interesting post. I think Ubuntu has some very good accessibility options, iv even seen refreshable brail somewhere but don't forget Ubuntu is not only free but open source. This means if you have an idea and the resorses to realize it you can modify Ubuntu to your hearts content. Maby if you post this on a developers forum you might find some support for your idea. There are many people deeper in the open source community who are looking for projects. Try asking around the http://sourceforge.net/ forums to get started and find interested developers. Good luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu offers a number of options to make the desktop more accessible to people with different physical abilities. Many of these options are included in the default install and can be accessed through the **Universal Access** menu in **System Setting**.

[image: system settings]

The **Seeing** tab offers high a contrast theme and and a screen reader for the visually impaired:

[image: seeing]

The **Hearing** offers visual alerts:

[image: hearing]

The **Typing** and **Pointing and Clicking** tabs offer options that may assist folks that have difficulties using a keyboard or mouse:

[image: typing]

[image: pointing]

More information about different accessibility options can be found on the [Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility). [The Ubuntu Accessibility team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AccessibilityTeam) has a [mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/Ubuntu-accessibility) where planning and discussion of accessibility features happen.

Answer (score 0):

You can help by getting in touch with other developers via IRC, on the Freenode network, under `#ubuntu-devel`. You can also try to improve accessibility [Paper Cuts](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PaperCut). I do understand your concern and would love to see some of your contributions!

Forhelp, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat.
Other ways of contributing are suggestions at [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com).

Answer (score 0):

What you want is either available or can be adapted.  This is the beauty of open source.

With all that being said the best place to find out more about this sort of thing is the documentation page and if on your journey you find out more you can upgrade that documentation because it is a wiki style user contribution page.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Accessibility

I'd be happy to help get you started in either changing some software or updating documentation if it isn't good enough.